# A test of 3 sections, where the first must the big as the browser window jQuery and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

*EDIT:* Solved by writing at the top of the page the Doctype -
    "< !DOCTYPE html >" (no spaces between tags < , > and other chars)

I'm doing a test with a page with inside four sections. The first of them must have the height of the browser window.
So, for do this I tested both jQuery and Javascript Code.
But while the JS-pure code works, jQuery's one doesn't.
The code are these:

jQuery:

```
$("section:first").css("min-height", $(window).height());
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("section:first").css("min-height", $(window).height());
});
```

Javascript:

```
var first = document.getElementsByTagName("section")[0];
first.style.minHeight = window.innerHeight + "px";
window.onresize = function() {
    first.style.minHeight = window.innerHeight + "px";
}
```

I've an iMac 1920x1080 and my Chrome browser height is 896px, but if I try to use the jQuery code (that doesn't get console error!), min-height number will grow by resizing the window (up or down) by height (always UP) and in base of numbers of other sections.
Does someone know why?

There is the HTML and CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url("images/bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 713px 518px;
}

.content {
    background-color: #FFF;
}

.internal {
    position: relative;
    padding: 1% 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #21D561;
}



<section> Some content here </section>

<section class="content">
   <div class="internal">
     <p>Here a big Lorem Ipsum in eight paragraphs</p>
   </div>
</section>

<section class="content">
   <div class="internal">
     <p>Here a big Lorem Ipsum in six paragraphs</p>
   </div>
</section>

<section class="content">
   <div class="internal">
     <p>Here a big Lorem Ipsum in six paragraphs</p>
   </div>
</section>
```

You can see the wrong result here: http://syrafiles.esy.es/learning/Static_Section/

Comment: because .height() returns an integer, whereas css needs `px`.

Answer (score 0):

In your pure JS you write:

```
var first = document.getElementsByTagName("section")[0];
first.style.minHeight = window.innerHeight + "px";
window.onresize = function() {
    first.style.minHeight = window.innerHeight + "px";
}
```

while leaving out `+ "px"` in jQuery:

```
$("section:first").css("min-height", $(window).height());
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("section:first").css("min-height", $(window).height());
});
```

Try instead:

```
$("section:first").css("min-height", $(window).height() + "px");
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("section:first").css("min-height", $(window).height() + "px");
});
```

`.height()` returns an integer only, you also need to add `+ "px"` here, just as you do in pure JS

Comment: I tried that, but doesn't work... See that to the link. :(
Also, if I try without "px" it get automatically to px...
Anyway, thank you!

Comment: try `$("section").filter(':first')`

Comment: also, do you have your jquery code wrapped inside the .ready() function?

Comment: Tried to add around that code $(document).ready(function() { ... }); and using the filter, but keep to be wrong :(

Comment: maybe add display: block for section css?

Comment: Tried adding section { display: block }, but nothing. The problem is: why that jQuery code (or all with CSS and HTML) make the first section's height not as my screen but more, like (now as now) 1168px? :/

Comment: The weird thing is that if you do $(window).height() in the console, you get the initial min-height value (1168)x2 = 2336 D:
And if you try to resize the browser windows, the min-height will increase anomalously D:

Comment: I discovered that the problem there is because the third section, but I can't understand why... :|

Comment: hm i dunno. try to create a jsfiddle and we'll see

Comment: A fiddle with the code I put inside the first post?

Comment: I can't belive this!! LOL
I solved by adding the DOCTYPE at the begin of the page (I forgot that) ahaha :D
Anyway, thank you for your help ;P (you can add this to your solution and I will check you for the solved!)